# spring boot test loads schema.sql defined in java/resources instead of test/resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have the following Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AccountsServerTest.class, PostgresSQLTestDbConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class NodeRepositoryTest {
......
}
```

and also I have schema.sql and data.sql scripts under `src/main/resources` which are supposed to be run when the app starts.

I also have another two sql files under `src/test/resources/` and I want to run them when NodeRepositoryTest is started.

However, for some reason, when I start NodeRepositoryTest, scripts from `src/main/resources` are executed.

Perhaps, someone had the same problem before?

I would really appreciate any help,

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually define the `.sql` scripts which should be applied to your test method/test class.

Have a look at the following example from the official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html):

```
@Test
@Sql({"/test-schema.sql", "/test-user-data.sql"})
public void userTest {
    // execute code that relies on the test data
}
```

Comment: The path to those files, is it relative to what folder?

Comment: This should be the classpath, you can read the Javadoc of `@Sql` to double-check.